# Wordpress Menu Selected State

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need help in changing the style of a `li` in selected state. I'm using a Custom wordpress template for my Pages. I dont wanna create several templates just to set the class of li on each pages to `.selected`.

anyway here is my code:

```
<nav class="topmenu">
<ul>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-2' ) ); ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I do have several pages and i added them in `menu-2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add .selected class to the menu. WordPress automatically adds following two classes to the current menu item. You can place the code of .selected class in these classes and it will work..

```
current-menu-item
current_page_item
```

Comment: I also have static menus inside my header.php, will wordpress automatically add those 2 classes on my static menu?

Comment: .menu li.current_page_item a, .menu li.current-cat a, .menu      li.current-menu-item a {
    background-color:#8dc63f;
    color:#fff;
}